# Dynamically create table rows with onClick events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am generating a table and when I create the rows I have a for loop like this:

```
 for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
     var row$ = $('<tr/>');
     for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
         if (columns[colIndex] == 'web_id'){
          cellValue = "<a onclick='showMoreData('myList[i][columns[colIndex]]')'>" + myList[i][columns[colIndex]] + "</a>"
         }
         else {
              var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];
         }

         if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }

         row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
     }
     $(".table").append(row$);
```

but this isn't working, what do I need to do to add an onclick event based on the row's content in a column so that I can add a dynamic link?

Comment: Nested single quotes may be the problem. Try `cellValue = "<a onclick=\"showMoreData('myList[i][columns[colIndex]]')\">" + myList[i][columns[colIndex]] + "</a>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `A` element, bind data to it and then you need to create event delegation and bind it to the table:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
    var row$ = $('<tr/>');

    for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
        var cellValue = '';
        if (columns[colIndex] == 'web_id'){
            // Set a data attribute with the colindex and add the class 'web_id' for the event delegation
            cellValue = "<a href=\"\" class=\"web_id\" data-index=\"" + myList[i][columns[colIndex]] + "\">" + myList[i][columns[colIndex]] + "</a>";
         } else {
             cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];
         }

        if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }

        row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
    }

    $(".table").append(row$);
}

// Bind a click event for every .web_id element in the table 
$('.table').on('click', '.web_id', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // You can put here the logic of the 'showMoreData()' function
    alert( $(this).data('index') ); 
});
```

This replace the need to add `onclick` to the `A` elements in the table, because I added a data attribute called `data-index` - This attribute will be available via the jquery's [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function.

I bind the click event using the event-delegation approach, which attaches an event handler to only one element, the `.table`, and the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked `.web_id` to '.table'). [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/)